# python text parsing from onenote response string

Tags: python, json, parsing

How do I parse a string like this into data structure. What parsing tool should I use?

```
u'{\r\n  "@odata.context":"https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/$metadata#me/notes/notebooks(\'0-AB87696357344A7E%212879\')/sections(parentNotebook(id,name,self),parentSectionGroup(id,name,self))","value":[\r\n    {\r\n      "id":"0-AB87696357344A7E!2881","self":"https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/me/notes/sections/0-AB87696357344A7E!2881","createdTime":"2017-05-18T01:14:32.977Z","name":"Untitled Section","createdBy":"Jason","createdByIdentity":{\r\n        "user":{\r\n          "id":"AB87696357344A7E","displayName":"Jason"\r\n        }\r\n      },"lastModifiedBy":"Jason","lastModifiedByIdentity":{\r\n        "user":{\r\n          "id":"AB87696357344A7E","displayName":"Jason"\r\n        }\r\n      },"lastModifiedTime":"2017-05-18T02:19:00.587Z","isDefault":false,"pagesUrl":"https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/me/notes/sections/0-AB87696357344A7E!2881/pages","parentNotebook@odata.context":"https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/$metadata#me/notes/notebooks(\'0-AB87696357344A7E%212879\')/sections(\'0-AB87696357344A7E%212881\')/parentNotebook(id,name,self)/$entity","parentNotebook":{\r\n        "id":"0-AB87696357344A7E!2879","name":"Companies and sectors","self":"https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/me/notes/notebooks/0-AB87696357344A7E!2879"\r\n      },"parentSectionGroup@odata.context":"https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/$metadata#me/notes/notebooks(\'0-AB87696357344A7E%212879\')/sections(\'0-AB87696357344A7E%212881\')/parentSectionGroup(id,name,self)/$entity","parentSectionGroup":null\r\n    }\r\n  ]\r\n}'
```

Comment: What do *you* consider as readable?

Comment: Import `json` module. And then use: `obj = json.loads(your_string)`. You can then say: `print(obj["@odata.context"])`.

Comment: @Stephen Rauch. what's readable? how would you parse it if you tried to read it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As SuperSaiyan mentioned in comments, this is a JSON string.  So is easily parsed with the json library:

```
import json
json_data = json.loads(
    u'{\r\n  "@odata.context":"https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/$metadata#me/notes/notebooks(\'0-AB87696357344A7E%212879\')/sections(parentNotebook(id,name,self),parentSectionGroup(id,name,self))","value":[\r\n    {\r\n      "id":"0-AB87696357344A7E!2881","self":"https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/me/notes/sections/0-AB87696357344A7E!2881","createdTime":"2017-05-18T01:14:32.977Z","name":"Untitled Section","createdBy":"Jason","createdByIdentity":{\r\n        "user":{\r\n          "id":"AB87696357344A7E","displayName":"Jason"\r\n        }\r\n      },"lastModifiedBy":"Jason","lastModifiedByIdentity":{\r\n        "user":{\r\n          "id":"AB87696357344A7E","displayName":"Jason"\r\n        }\r\n      },"lastModifiedTime":"2017-05-18T02:19:00.587Z","isDefault":false,"pagesUrl":"https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/me/notes/sections/0-AB87696357344A7E!2881/pages","parentNotebook@odata.context":"https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/$metadata#me/notes/notebooks(\'0-AB87696357344A7E%212879\')/sections(\'0-AB87696357344A7E%212881\')/parentNotebook(id,name,self)/$entity","parentNotebook":{\r\n        "id":"0-AB87696357344A7E!2879","name":"Companies and sectors","self":"https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/me/notes/notebooks/0-AB87696357344A7E!2879"\r\n      },"parentSectionGroup@odata.context":"https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/$metadata#me/notes/notebooks(\'0-AB87696357344A7E%212879\')/sections(\'0-AB87696357344A7E%212881\')/parentSectionGroup(id,name,self)/$entity","parentSectionGroup":null\r\n    }\r\n  ]\r\n}'
)
print(type(json_data))
print(json_data['value'][0]['createdBy'])
```

**Results:**

```
<type 'dict'>
Jason
```

Comment: thanks. i put it into a dataframe afterwards. `obj=json.loads(r.text)
df = pd.DataFrame(obj.get('value', []))` . Very readable in a `df`